# moment.js returns invalid Date for moment (String, string)

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, cypress

Wants to compare the timestamp. Tried lots of ways but it is throwing an Invalid Date error. The variables `startDate /endDate/testDate` returns a same timestamp format in `'DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:ss' i.e. '21.12.2021 08:29:00'`

```
var startDate = cy.get('[data-placeholder="Select time range (from)"]').invoke('val')
var endDate = cy.get('[data-placeholder="Select time range (to)"]').invoke('val')
var testDate  = cy.get('td:nth-child(5)>span').invoke('text')

1. moment(startDate ,'DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:ss' ).format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:ss')  ///  returns Invalid Date 
2.  moment(startDate ,'DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:ss' ).format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:ss').valueOf() ///  returns Invalid Date
3. moment(startDate ,'DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:ss' ).format()  ///  returns Invalid Date 
4. moment(startDate ,'DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:ss' ) ///  returns Invalid Date
```

Also tried using isBetween() function. But for all the conditions it is throwing result as `false`.

```
       cy.log( moment(testDate , 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:ss').isBetween(
            (moment(startDate,'DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:ss')), (moment(endDate,'DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:ss'))
            ) )
```

please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

[momentjs docs screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzLoF.png)

`MM` in `HH:MM:ss` should be small letters. That is, `moment('21.12.2021 08:29:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss')` should work fine.